# holomorphic solution with respect to a parameter of the differential equation

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking at the following problem 
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t)=f(t,a)x(t),\\
x(0)=v\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}, 
\end{cases}

where $f:\mathbb{R}\times\Omega\to \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a matrix-valued function, continuous in the $t$-variable and holomorphic for the $a$-variable in $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$. I would like to prove that $x(1)$ is holomorphic with respect to the $a$-variable.

In particular, $f(t,a)$ can be expressed as
$$ f(t,a)=f_0(t)+\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f_i(t)}{a^{i}},$$
where  $f_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is a real-valued continuous matrix function, for every $i=0,\ldots,n$.

*NOTE* from the following [StackExchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126539/picard-lindel%C3%B6f-theorem-with-parameter-what-regularity), it is possible to analyze the following equivalent problem 
\begin{cases}
\dot{z}(t)=F(t,z),\\
z(0)=\tilde{v}\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\}, 
\end{cases}
where $z=(x,a)^T$ and $\dot{z}(t)=F(t,z)$ stands for 
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}(t)=f(t,a)x(t),\\
\dot{a}(t)=0.  
\end{cases}